# What is causing the error when trying to start mssql-server on Linux Mint using sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup, and how can it be resolved?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, sqlserver

This is the error that is popping up! I am trying to install sql server 2019. I read in one github question that this isn't an mssql-server error but something that has to do with the linux itself, or my device to be more specific, but still couldn't do anything about it. I would appreciate it a lot if someone helped me with this. Thanks!

```
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Sat Mar 25 01:30:57 2023
The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000001
         Signal: SIGSEGV - Segmentation fault (11)
 Signal Address: (nil)
    Signal Code: 0x00000001
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 000055615e53f822 <unknown>
                 000055615e53f240 <unknown>
                 000055615e55a872 <unknown>
                 000055615e4d24fb <unknown>
                 00007fe75ba6a520 __sigaction+0x50
                 0000000000000000 <unknown>
                 000055615e4ee4ee <unknown>
                 000055615e4ce7a4 <unknown>
                 000055615e4ce5c9 <unknown>
        Process: 38589 - sqlservr
         Thread: 38715 (application thread 0x1d0)
    Instance Id: ecd3af55-b388-444f-aeae-7fa1f77b951b
       Crash Id: 0a3e20d4-4fbb-4ee2-ad24-d5ead7235f1a
    Build stamp: da729593fa9bc048da0037e5e85e1b296f1e5a8fbc8e1385d683b5b22fa891e1
   Distribution: Linux Mint 21.1
     Processors: 8
   Total Memory: 8006934528 bytes
      Timestamp: Sat Mar 25 01:30:57 2023
Capturing a dump of 38589
Successfully captured dump: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.3_25_2023_1_30_57.38589
Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
     handle-crash.sh
     /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
     38589
     /opt/mssql/bin
     /var/opt/mssql/log/
     
     ecd3af55-b388-444f-aeae-7fa1f77b951b
     0a3e20d4-4fbb-4ee2-ad24-d5ead7235f1a
     
     /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.3_25_2023_1_30_57.38589

Linux Mint 21.1
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
/usr/bin/tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: Permission denied
Sat Mar 25 01:31:00 AM CET 2023 Capturing program information
Dump already generated: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.3_25_2023_1_30_57.38589, moving to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.38589.temp/core.sqlservr.38589.gdmp
Moving logs to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.38589.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log
Sat Mar 25 01:31:00 AM CET 2023 Capturing program binaries
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/local/openssl-3.0.7/test-runs/test_rehash/rehash.231763’: Permission denied
Sat Mar 25 01:31:02 AM CET 2023 Compressing the dump files
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.03_25_2023_01_30_59.38589.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

I tried deleting mssql-server fully and then reinstalling it but it just doesn't work. I tried to manually install it, yet still not working and it is the same output always.

Comment: I read `Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.`. Are there anything interesting there ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Chances are there will be a mismatch in the libs somewhere and good luck finding that. If you want to run mssql, then given how complicated such things are, then you are better to run it on a supported system. If you really want it to run on this release of Mint, then start it manually, turn on all debugging, run strace & ltrace against it, hunt through the copious amounts of info returned and hopefully you will find where the problem lies. Notify Microsoft of the problem, try it on Centos Steam.